# ATHENA CREATE TABLE AS problem with parquet format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parquet, create-table, amazon-athena

I'm creating a table in Athena and specifying the format as PARQUET however the file extension is not being recognized in S3. The type is displayed as "-" which means that the file extension is not recognized despite that I can read the files (written from Athena) successfully in a Glue job using:

`df = spark.read.parquet()`

Here is my statement:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
    numeric_field INT
    ,numeric_field2 INT)

STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://xxxxxxxxx/TEST TABLE/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('classification'='PARQUET');   
    
INSERT INTO test
VALUES (10,10),(20,20);
```

I'm specifying the format as PARQUET but when I check in the S3 bucket the file type is displayed as "-". Also when I check the glue catalog, that table type is set as 'unknown'

[S3 STORAGE PRINT SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VySTx.png)

I expected that the type is recognized as "parquet" in the S3 bucket

Comment: The file type displayed in the S3 console is irrelevant. Are you able to use the parquet file in your relevant data application?

Comment: Yes I'm. I just wanted to understand why Athena wasn't creating the correct file extension. Even by consulting the glue catalog, table type was set as unknown what was a little odd

Comment: The 'type' shown in Amazon S3 is set by the `content-type` metadata when an object is created. This is how browsers know what type of file is being downloaded, so it can choose to display it in a tab or download it as a file. Amazon Athena does not set this metadata value on the object. However, it has no negative impact on your ability to use the parquet files.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to specify the `content-type` metadata from Athena via `TBLPROPERTIES`? I mean, it doesn't really matter  because I can still use/read the files written from Athena. Just wondering

Answer (score 2):

After contacting the AWS support, it was confirmed that with CTAS queries Athena does not create file extensions for parquet files.
"Further to confirm this, I do see the Knowledge Center article [1] where CTAS generates the Parquet files without extension ( Under section 'Convert the data format and set the approximate file size' Point 5)."

However the files written from Athena, even without the extension are readable.

Reference:
[1] https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/set-file-number-size-ctas-athena/

Workaround: I created a function to change the file extension. Basically iterating over the files in the S3 bucket and then writing the contents back to the same location with parquet file extension